# Arduino MKR Zero problem with new UART comunication

Tags: arduino-ide, mkr1000, arduino-zero

I'm currently using an *Arduino MKR Zero* board and I need to add a new communication because the *Serial1* on pins 13 and 14 is already used by another device.

I've followed [this](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SamdSercom) tutorial from *Arduino* official website to create a new serial communication, but using the given code **I have no communication on pins 0 and 1**.

The code compiles, but it doesn't work when uploaded to the *MKR Zero* board.
I've noted that *IrqHandler()* is not highlighted in my *Arduino IDE* (it remains black).

So, should I install some library?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the issue? I also struggle to get an additional serial interface to work.

Answer (score 1):

When a library does not highlight, it might be that the library is not coded to be highlighted (see [here](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=202136.0)).

If you installed the library yourself, you may have put it in the wrong path.